# Jquery animate becomes jerky when added piece of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My animation becomes jerky and slow when I add this piece of javascript:

```
window.location.hash = image.attr("data-imgnum");
```

Is this normal? Is there a jquery alternative that maybe works faster and doesn't slow down everything?

This is full code: http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLB/7/

But since on jsfiddle hash thing doesn't work animation works fine...

Comment: What's the animation?

Comment: what is the "my animation" you're talking about? When does it get slow? What do you mean by "everything". Could you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: What is `image object`? Please show your full code.

Comment: @SimonM Updated question with js fiddle.

Comment: @WillemMulder Updated question with js fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if there is an element with ID same as your `data-imgnum` attribute. If there is, then browser default behavior on `hashchange` event is to jump to the element with ID specified by hash `part` of the URL, which can affect scrolling animations (or others depending on `scrollTop` param).

If it doesn't help, check if your website has somehow implemented `hashchange` event, and check the code behind it.

Question is very specific so it could help if you add more details about whole environment.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze - as you noticed it works fine on jsfiddle. Did you try looking for `hashchange` event/plugin?

Comment: It doesn't work fine on jsfidle, hash tags don't change at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you have `image` object exists in your page.

Also `attr` is `jQuery function`, so check that you have added a `version` of `jquery`.

If you have not added jquery then try your code like:

```
document.getElementById('image').getAttribute("data-imgnum");
//let image has id attribute 'image'
```

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute

Comment: I have added jquery. Image exists.

Comment: I can't see `data-imgnum` in any `image`.

Comment: Sorry it is in my backend though, I didn't copy html correctly :)